# Send Value to another File

Tags: python, class, tkinter, widget

I write a small GUI with a Wiki and I try to Split my Main and the Wiki GUI and Functions. I managed to have a Frame in my Main where I "load" the Wiki GUI. Now I have a entry in my Main where I also want to search through the Wiki. So I have to call a function from the Wiki File and send a value. But the problem is that nothing happens. But the print get executed.

This are my two files, but shortened:

```
import Wiki
#[...]

class MyFirstGUI(object):
    def __init__(self, master):

    #[...]    
    self.gui_control = ttk.Notebook(master)
    self.wiki_gui = ttk.Frame(self.gui_control, borderwidth=0)


    self.wiki_search = Entry(master, width=27,font=("Century Gothic",10))
    self.wiki_search.grid(row=11,column=0,padx=17 ,pady=0, sticky=N+W)
    self.wiki_search.bind('<Return>',self.send_search)

    # This is how i placed my WikiFrame
    e3 = Wiki.WikiFrame(self.wiki_gui)
    e3.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="NESW") 

    def send_search(self,event):
        wiki = Wiki.WikiFrame(self.wiki_gui)        
        wiki.fill_wiki_value(self.wiki_search.get())
```

Wiki File:

```
import tkinter as tk

class WikiFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(4, weight=1)

        self.Search_Entry = tk.Entry(self, width=20,font=("Century Gothic",12))
        self.Search_Entry.grid(row=0,column=2, sticky='NESW', padx=10)

    def fill_wiki_value(self,value):
        print('Hello')
        self.Search_Entry.insert(tk.END, value)
```

Comment: When you send_search is you intention to create a new WikiFrame or use e3?

Comment: In fill_wiki_value can you print the entry text after it is set?

Comment: I think I did it, 'e3.fill_wiki_value(self.wiki_search.get())' and delete 'wiki = Wiki.WikiFrame(self.wiki_gui)' did the trick.

Comment: You must have been populating a wiki entry that was not being displayed, while viewing e3.

Comment: Greedy answer posted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entry is being set on a separate wiki frame and not the one being displayed 'e3'.